# If then statement in the for loop

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I'm nebiew for windows scripting. My scripts would seachs string in the file, if counted the string and checking return code in if then else statment. But, I have question, some error on if then statment show [%i] was unexpected in this time.

```
@echo off
cd C:\script\
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ( 'find /C "ANR2034E" checkout.txt' ) do ( echo %%i )
if [/I] [%%i] == [1]  ( echo %%i ) else ( echo No ) )
```

Furthermore, May I integrate if statement in the for loop?

example:

```
for %%i in ('command') do ( if [/I] [%%i] == [i] (command) else (command))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd C:\script\
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('find /C "ANR2034E" checkout.txt') do (
    echo %%i
    if [%%i]==[1] (
        echo %%i
    ) else (
        echo No
    )
)
```

The error was because you had `/i` after the `if` within square brackets. In any case `/i` (case insensitivity) is not required because you've used `find /c` which will return only an integer.

As you can see, the `if` condition can definitely be included within the `for` loop.

Comment: in addition I  suggest you to look at the PowerShell. It's built into system since windows xp sp3 and has much "sane" syntax.